# importing data from one excel sheet to another?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having 2 `datasheets` in one excel file. i want to import `complete columns` from one `datasheet` to another.

Remember i have to import complete columns like column a, b, c etc.

Is there any way to do so without manually copying each and every cell in the `datasheets`?

Right now I copy one cell at a time, that too manually. And that is a very painful and non efficient method.

thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just select whole columns and copy-paste?

Answer (score 2):

To select an entire column, simply left-click on the letter of the column you want. To select multiple columns, click and drag over the appropriate columns. The other method is to select the top cell, then press `Shift+Ctrl+[Down Arrow]`, which selects the last occupied row (or the very last row if there's no values in between).

That said, you may want to look up some Excel tutorials since this is pretty basic stuff. It'll boost your confidence and knowledge, and you may even be able to help others!

[image: derp]